# Workflow in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, workflow

I need to do the following as a workflow - I know how to do the first part, but not sure how to then assign the document to a new list with an ID number.  Any thoughts?  I'm very new to this and can't think of even how to outline this in a workflow chart.

Create a flow diagram for a workflow that forwards a document from a list via an email to an approver.  Once the approver signs, then that signed document is forwarded to another list where an identification number is assigned.

Thanks!